# Can't acces cookie from frontend after settting it in backend in a different port. Using Redis

Tags: express, session, cookies, redis, backend

I've been trying to find a solution to my issue but I couldn't really figure out as to what I should do.

So I am trying to setup a basic authentication with sessions using Redis as session store with express and Next.js as frontend.

My backend is listening for port 3001 and my frontend is in 3000.

The issue / what I want to do is to be able to protect a page if there is no session configured.

I can't seem to both write the session to the screen or log it. It is simply not accessible through frontend. I have couple of theories but I've been trying to solve it for hours now.

I am attaching the code here:

**The frontend function in the Home (signup page) that handles the interaction with backend**

```
const onLogin = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3001/login",
      {
        username,
        password,
        email,
      },
      { withCredentials: true }
    );

    const { isSuccesfull } = response.data;

    if (isSuccesfull) {
      router.push("/dashboard");
    }
  };
```

*If the authentication is fine then the session should be set and the page should be directed to "/dashboard".*

**The Backend;**

```
const { redisStore } = require("./utilies/redis");
const loginRoute = require("./routes/loginRoute");
const { corsOptions } = require("./config");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const loginController = require("./controllers/loginController");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    store: redisStore,
    secret: "mysecret",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password, email, id } = req.body;
  // const result = await Model.insertUser(username, password, email);
  req.session.userSession = id;
  res.status(200).send({ isSuccesfull: "true" });
});

// When make a request to this path it should return the userSession with was setted above. But It doesn't seem to work. 

app.get("/dashboard", (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ isAuthenticated: true, sessionData: req.session.userSession ? true : false });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**The Dashboard Page :**

In here I want to redirect to home page (signup page) if there is no session registered. But I couldn't get the session in anyway :/ .

```
import React from "react";
import { auth } from "./auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { stringify } from "querystring";

export default async function Dashboard() {
  const { isAuthenticated, sessionData } = await auth();
  if (!sessionData) redirect("/");

  return <div>{stringify(sessionData)}</div>;
}
```

**Finally the Auth function above**

```
import axios from "axios";

export async function auth() {
  const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/dashboard", {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: { "Origin-Allow-Credentials": true },
  });

  return response.data;
}
```

I've tried a lot of examples in here but there is something missing. I couldn't found out what. But in short I want to be able to access the session data that I set from the backend in frontend. I don't know if them being in different ports matter but I would be supper dubber appreciated if you could help me. Thanks!